# How to know if model is overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model, overfitting

I understand that using cross validation we can validate our model, but it is also possible that maybe our model is underfitting; hence, providing wrong results. One possibility that I can think of is that if even after making our model less complex results are not right then our model might be underfitting, it is just a guess!

Please write if anything I am missing or any other way to decide whether our model is overfitting or underfitting?

Answer (score 8):

You can determine the difference between an underfitting and overfitting experimentally by comparing fitted models to training-data and test-data.

Typical graphs:

[a](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131233/neural-network-over-fitting)

[image]

[b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160902/is-it-possible-for-test-error-to-be-lower-than-training-error)
[image]

[c](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23331/why-is-there-an-asymmetry-between-the-training-step-and-evaluation-step) 
[image]

[d](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184103/why-the-error-on-a-training-set-is-decreasing-while-the-error-on-the-validation)
[image]

---

These plots will show you the accuracy of the model, as function of some parameter (e.g. 'complexity'), for *both* the

- **training-data** (the data use for fitting)
- and **test data** (data kept separate from the training phase)

One normally chooses the model that does the best on the *test-data*. If you deviate then for...

- For **underfitting models**, you do worse because they do not capture the true trend sufficiently.

  If you get more underfitting then you get both **worse fits for training and testing data**.
- for **overfitting models**, you do worse because they respond too much to the noise, rather than the true trend.

  If you get more overfitting then you get **better fits for training data** (capturing the noise, but it is useless or even detrimental), but still **worse for testing data**.

After performing these steps, you should remain in sight that, while you may have selected the least underfitting/overfitting model out of your options, this does not mean that there would not be some other better model.

In particular: the true model, might be an overfitting model in circumstances of high noise-signal ratios (see  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299523/164061 )

Comment: The first plot seems to show error over training time.

Comment: @Tim Training time makes a model (e.g. an artificial neural network) better in fitting the training data (increases complexity) but not necessarily the testing data. Thus it is related to overfitting vs. underfitting.

Comment: More direct approach: use a proper accuracy scoring rule (log-likelihood, etc.) to compare the simple model with a model that generalizes the simple model.  This assesses adequacy of the simple model.  If it's not adequate, it's underfit.

Comment: @FrankHarrell log-likelihood may not always be straightforward to express. For GLM and such things with clearly expressible error distributions it is, but beyond that?

Comment: Log-likelihood and Bayesian counterparts are available in any fully-specified statistical model.  This is related to efficient pseudo R^2 measures and AIC.

Answer (score 0):

A sign of **Underfitting** could be when the accuracy of the test and training are very similar. The way to "fix" it and through "tuning".

If you are trainning a NN you could increase the number of training cycles, on the other hand, if you are working with traditionalML, for example a Logistic Regression, you coudl try to tune certain parameters(that come by default) of the algorithm that leas to a better perfomance of this, in the case of Logistic Regression it would be changing the differente values of C

i.e

signal of underfitting, then I tune my model

```
# default
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=0)
```

worst performance, discard it

```
# instantiate the model
logreg001 = LogisticRegression(C=0.01, solver='liblinear', random_state=0)
```

it improves performance so I keep it.

```
# instantiate the model
logreg100 = LogisticRegression(C=100, solver='liblinear', random_state=0)
```